# Why doesn't Aperture show black as black?

Tags: color-management, apple-aperture, display-calibration, color-black

Aperture seems to be displaying my images brighter than they actually are -- this makes colors seem washed out and makes it very difficult to accurately adjust the black point and other exposure parameters.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Aperture in full screen mode demonstrating the black point problem]

Notice that the loupe (set to the same magnification as the zoomed-in image) is more saturated, and blacks are blacker than the surrounding image.

Also compare the bottom edge of the image to the black strip just below it.

This happens even for totally black images, and is independent of any image adjustments:

[image: A totally black image displaying the black point problem in Aperture.]

Why is Aperture messing with my colors like this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've accidentally turned on Onscreen Proofing, which is used to simulate the colors of a final output medium like CMYK ink on paper. Turn it off by going to the View menu and clicking Onscreen Proofing, or hitting Option-Shift-P

[image: Aperture 3's View menu with Onscreen Proofing highlighted]

Comment: I believe you figured it out Evan...but I'd like to add another piece of critical information to any else reading. Monitors do not show accurate color unless you've put your time into color correction. The "Onscreen Proofing" is 'attempting' to correct the displayed image to match what it believes is the final output. If you want accurate prints you would use Onscreen Proofing after you've made adjustments to your icc profiles.